# Python Regex compile with variable

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "These are roses and lilies and orchids, but not marigolds or .."
r = re.compile(r'\roses\b | \bmarigolds\b | \borchids\b', flags=re.I | re.X)
print(r.findall(s))
```

Is it possible to add variables to the re.compile words?

```
keyword1 = 'roses'
keyword2 = 'marigolds'
keyword3 = 'orchids'
```

Comment: Note `\r` is a carriage return, not `r`.

Comment: `re.compile(r'\b{}\b | \b{}\b | \b{}\b'.format('roses', 'marigolds', 'orchids'), flags=re.I | re.X)`